# How to implement Configure method alternative in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

How to implement the following code in `ASP.NET Core 3.1` for `SignalR` serializer?

```
  services.AddOptions<JsonHubProtocolOptions>()
             .Configure<IServiceProvider>(opt, prov) =>
               {
                 opt.PayloadSerializerSettings = CreateSerializerSettings(prov);
              });
```

The code above was written for `ASP.NET Core 2.x`

But in the new `API` i should use `services.AddSignalR().AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol`. This method doesn't have `IServiceProvider` param in a callback. How to register `NewtonJsonProtocol` using `IServiceProvider` abilities?

In a few words:
I'm trying to use Dependency Injection inside `AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol` method, but how ?

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'm trying to use Dependency Injection inside AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol method